# Improving bulk inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, bulkinsert

I have a process, that among other things needs to keep an audit of what it does. This audit is an INSERT into an audit table.  I benchmarked it and it seems that this audit is making the process run slow (two orders of magnitude).
The audit table has some indexes on it, would it be a good idea to drop ALL indexes and rebuild them once the process ends?

The table structure is id(fk) | text | id(indexed) | id (indexed) | about 10 more text fields

I have a buffer of 50, when it fills up, I insert it all as bulk insert. Overall I insert about 300K records.

Comment: What is the table schema?  What query exactly are you running - a single INSERT with many rows' worth of values, or one INSERT query per row?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MyISAM, you can use ALTER TABLE auditTable DISABLE KEYS, then re-enable your keys (ALTER TABLE auditTable ENABLE KEYS) after you're done with your insert. However, this will only disable nonunique keys.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

> This feature can be activated explicitly for a MyISAM table. ALTER
>   TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes

If you have large PK/Unique keys, dropping the keys then adding them back after your import would likely be a lot faster.

You could also try writing your audit records to a flat file, then import them all at once using LOAD DATA INFILE. Again, disabling or droping your keys prior to the LOAD DATA will speed things up considerably.